# I want to change the background color of the HTML table for each row, but on a smartphone it changes for each cell

Tags: html, css, html-table, background, background-color

When I wrote the code below, it was displayed normally in developer mode (smartphone emulation) on a PC, but when I checked it on an actual device, the design collapsed.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tr {
  background-image: linear-gradient(40deg, #fce043 0%, #fb7ba2 74%);
}

table tr:last-child * {
  border-bottom: none;
}

table th,
table td {
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 2px #fff;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>見出し</th>
    <td>データ</td>
    <td>データ</td>
    <td>データ</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>見出し</th>
    <td>データ</td>
    <td>データ</td>
    <td>データ</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>見出し</th>
    <td>データ</td>
    <td>データ</td>
    <td>データ</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>見出し</th>
    <td>データ</td>
    <td>データ</td>
    <td>データ</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

・Display result - PC developer mode (smartphone emulation):
[image]

・Display result - Actual smartphone:
[image]

I want to reflect the background color setting for each row, but it is reflected for each cell.
(I want to reflect the same display results as the PC developer mode (smartphone emulation) on the actual smartphone.)

Please let me know how I can resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

Add Webkit Properties , This will allow your CSS to apply on different browsers

```
background: -o-linear-gradient();
background: -webkit-gradient(); /* Older webkit syntax */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient();
background: -ms-linear-gradient();
```

Comment: I tried this code, but the result is the same.